# Update textboxes based on checkboxes Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I want to achieve following thing with Jquery

- There are multiple trips and each trip has checkbox and textbox.
- Whenever checkbox is checked then the value in textbox corresponding to that checkbox must be updated to "1" .
- ehenever customer types in textbox then checkbox shall be checked.
- Customer is not allowed to choose more than 10 trips in total. (i.e. if both input box total is 10 then there shall be error or alert shown.

I tried by following code but it is not working

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ckval1" class="checkvaloare" /> Trip 1
<input type="text" id="text1" class="ckval1" size="2" />
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="ckval2" class="checkvaloare" /> Trip 2
<input type="text" id="text2" class="ckval2" size="2" />
```

JQuery as below:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
   update();
});

function update() {
   $("input[type=text]").each(function () {
    if (($(this).is(":checked"))) {
        $(this).val(1);
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).val(0);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `.next()` get next sibling element and `.prev()` get previous sibling element.

try

```
$(function () {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").on('click', function () {

        $(this).next().val($(this).is(':checked') ? '1' : '0');
    });
    $("input[type=text]").on('keyup', function () {
        if (+ $(this).val()) {
            alert('f');
            $(this).prev().prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $(this).prev().prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tamilcselvan/m242bo5z/2/

Comment: this worked... and also what about two conditions? whenever i textbox some value then corresponding checkbox shall be checked

Comment: You have a typo in your fiddle: `if (+ $(this).val()) {` -- the `+` breaks it. Remove that, it works great.

Comment: @TamilSelvan See if you can fix this up to address OP's 4th condition. It works, but not if text typed into 3rd textbox: http://jsfiddle.net/m242bo5z/3/  Over to you now...

Comment: @Tamil Selvan .... what if my HTMl is chnaged to <input type="checkbox" id="ckval1" class="checkvaloare" />Trip 1 <a href="">sad</a>
<input type="text" id="text1" class="ckval1" size="2" />.. then i have to use two `.next()` but i do not want to use `.next()` two times

Answer (score -1):

Two issues:

- you can change a checkbox without clicking it
- in your function, you are using $this) to refer to the checkbox, but it refers to the text input

Try something like this:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function (e) {
   update(e.target);
});

function update(el) {
   $("input[type=text]").each(function () {
    if (($(el).is(":checked"))) {
        $(this).val(1);
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).val(0);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: with your solution.. both textbox values getting updated. so not accepted. here is fiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/ae629/25/`

Comment: With the current html, you can't tell which checkbox goes with which text box. You would need to wrap each pair in a container element, and then update by selecting the parent of the checkbox, then finding the text box in it.

Comment: we can very well do it by using .next()